# Is the request timing information in rails accurate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling, timing

In a rails (2.3.8) app, my server log in development mode shows lines like these:

```
Completed in 265ms (View: 212, DB: 8)
```

What accounts for the missing 45ms? Even when repeating a request that does hardly anything, the timing information often reads:

```
Completed in 14ms (View: 1, DB: 1)
```

Is the remaining time anything to do with framework overhead, or is it all caused by non-database code in the action's ruby method, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time in your controller. with no made some Request. try to do a sleep in your controller action and you can see the global time arised but not view and DB.